# Show or hide SVG elements based on zoom level

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

I would like to hide text in an SVG image unless the  image is zoomed in. 
Since [min-zoom attribute](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/WG/wiki/Proposals/Zoom_feature_for_media_queries) is not yet implemented in most of the browsers, is there a workaround in this scenario using CSS,Javascript, SVG specific or any other  methods

Here is what I am trying to do(But wont work at the moment as min-zoom attribute is not available in most of the browsers :

```
<svg width="400" height="200">
  <rect width="300" height="100" style="fill:white;stroke-width:3;stroke:black" />
  <text class="mytext" x="100" y="55" fill="black" display="none">I love SVG!</text>
</svg>
```

**CSS**

```
@media screen and (min-zoom: 2)
    {.mytext{ display: inline; }
    }
```

Comment: Alter the visibility or display CSS properties in javascript depending on the zoom value

Comment: @RobertLongson, Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution using jquery. Below example will display the text if the browser zoom level is at least 2

Zoom detection code is taken from this [link](https://gist.github.com/kevingessner/5598913)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <svg width="400" height="200" >
        <rect width="300" height="100" style="fill:white;stroke-width:3;stroke:black" />
        <text id="mytext" x="100" y="55" fill="black" display="none">I love SVG!</text>
    </svg>
    <iframe id="frame" style="display:none;"> </iframe>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var elFrame = $('#frame')[0];
        $(elFrame.contentWindow).resize(function() {
            $(window).trigger('zoom');
        });
        $(window).on('zoom', function() {
            console.log('zoom', window.devicePixelRatio);
            if(window.devicePixelRatio >= 2) {
            $('#mytext').attr("display","inline");
            }else{
            $('#mytext').attr("display","none");
            }
        });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```